# How to turn on light blue flashy highlights of elements on webpage during editation of CSS code (VS code)?

Tags: css

When you hover over tags of elements in developer tools, then the tags are highlighted blue.
I saw a youtube video. Whenever the guy clicked on another element's code in CSS (VS Code), the element flashed light blue for a second on his webpage. What extension was he using?

**the video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DaQx3ULPLRw
time 5:30**

**[enter image description here]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGtiW.png**

Comment: have you a screenshot ?

Comment: Probebly *Emmet LiveStyle*